Apply affine transformation to LiDAR .las file
I'am currently working on a project that use a Local Coordinate system, and I need to reproject the file to UTM WGS84, to be able to load it to qgis.
I have the formula and values to reproject the data (for private reason, I can`t show the abcd values):
x_WGS84 = a* x_Local - b* y_Local + c
y_WGS84 = b* x_Local + a* y_Local + d

I tried using qgis and LAStools to apply the affine transformation, but didn't work. I probably miss a step/command.
My last attempt in LAStools was:
las2las -i input.las  -transform_matrix a,-b,0 b,a,0 0,0,0 c,d,0 -o output.las

(I even tried apply the formula in python, but the LAS its ~20GB, to big for my computer)
Help ):
